# CSS3 Overlapping div tags in keyframes

Tags: animation, css, html

I trying to make a simple animated menu that slides in and out but i have stumbled on getting the div's to overlap as required.

http://jsfiddle.net/bluestreak/eQcsc/

It currently animates well but doesn't over lap. and I have tried all manner of combinations of positioning.

Comment: can you post your desired result image than we will get idea exact idea about your requirment...

Comment: Here is a quick sketch: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-jvlQbYqTz-SHRRYTRidkFBNDg

Comment: The sketch basically shows the layout of the page in question. the animation will eventually be taller and will fit in the middle with the arrows on the sketch. The idea is for it to be an animated menu. upon loading the page it continuously scrolls from right to left showing different items that I can change. I then ultimately want to be able to allow the user to click on one of the tab headings to expand that banner into the middle with a further link to the required page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all your infomenu IDs position:absolute

Comment: Hi, This works but creates a new problem. In the page I have this in it actually sits inside another div box. With this setting changed, it moves this animation to the top of the page. any idea how to keep it in its original position?

Comment: try putting position:relative on the containing div :)